# Joining Collections and Assigning values

Tags: c#, linq, join, collections

I have two collections and i want to join them based on key attribute and assign one collection's values to other. I am doing it in following way

```
var joinedData =   from collection_one in Office.Employees 
               join collection_two in NewOffice.Employees 
                  on collection_1.OfficeId equals collection_two.OfficeId
               select new { collection_one, collection_two};


// Declare a new Collection 

ICollection<Office.Employees> updatedCollection = New List<Office.Employees>();

// Assign New Collection_Two Values to Collection_One
foreach (var item in joinedData.ToList())
            {
                item.collection_one.Deleted = item.collection_two.Deleted;
                updatedCollection .Add(item.obp);
            }
```

this is not producing the right result. My Join is producing more records than it should for an inner join. Can anyone spot an issue ?

Comment: Your query looks fine to me. Can you share some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try left join using DefaultIfEmpty() :

```
    var updatedCollection =
        (from collection_one in Office.Employees 
         from collection_two in NewOffice.Employees.Where(x => x.OfficeId == collection_one.OfficeId).DefaultIfEmpty()
         where collection_two == null
         select new { 
             collection_one, 
             collection_two
         }).Select(x => {
            x.collection_one.Deleted = x.collection_two.Deleted;
            return x.obp;
         });
```

But what is x.obp? Maybe result should be x.collection_one?